# ImageView with background leaves margin when image is loaded

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have my imageview declared like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/category_image_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:maxHeight="170dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@drawable/image_placeholder"
        />
```

And this is how I set my category_image_top in asynctask (on onPostExecute)

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
```

When image is set, imageview suddenly gets a margin of 4px. But when I remove android:background="@drawable/image_placeholder" from XML everything is fine?!

BTW: image_placeholder is a 9-patch image, if this makes any difference.

Any ideas why this happens?

UPDATE: I've tried placing background as a solid color and then no margins appear when image is loaded. I've also tried placing another 9-patch image and when I do so margins appear again. So it must be something with background as an image

UPDATE2: Maybe it's an android bug like this guy points out? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8340745/581531

Comment: try placing a parent linear layout with only a background color on it. Something different to your image and the background of the app eg bright green. If the image has a transparent 4px border as suggested you will only see the green when the setImageBitmap is called (I'd put this in a button call so you can trigger it on demand to find the issue). If a parent of the imageview has a margin you will not see the green. This should help try to identify the problem. Honestly the 4px transparent border is more likely.

Comment: This is the deal.. If I put a solid color as background to my imageview then everything is OK. I tried what you suggested but my background image has no transparent pixels so my linearlayout background isn't seen "through" imageview

Comment: It sounds like your 9 Patching is wrong. Is the 9 patching working?

Comment: I've used Android 9-patch tool (Draw 9-patch) and it looks good in it. Images is displayed properly it just interferes with my src image. Should src image override all background stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Solution was found, maybe it's not the prettiest one but hey, it work! :)

In my view I've just added an arbitrary View that is a holder for my image. On top of it i have my ImageView so when the image is loaded placeholder (View) get covered. This is my view (or at least part that matters):

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >

        <View 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:background="@drawable/image_placeholder"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/article_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I can guess that image_placeholder has 4px transparent margin

Comment: check it.. it doesnt have any shadows or transparent pixels

Answer (score 0):

<s>The element that contains the image view may have a margin, have you checked that?</s>

Change `android:background="@drawable/image_placeholder"` to `android:src="@drawable/image_placeholder"`

Also add the following: `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

If centerCrop doesn't work, try the other ones listed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

Comment: nope.. no margin.. if I remove background image displays properly

Comment: if I do this my 9-patch is stretched really weirdly. I have a fixed logo in the middle of the 9-patch, and if I set it to src it gets stretched, but if I set it as background it looks OK :S

Comment: if I set my 9-patch as a src it gets distorted (blurry and fixed content is scaled). Try all the scale types but non of them fits

Comment: Are you sure you've done the 9 patching right? Maybe just try it without the 9 patching